# How to display Date in Html using angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two datepickeres in my HTML file using bootstrap and I am trying to display a simple message from this (first selected date) to this (second selected date).

The typescript class is:

```
 export class Datepicker {
    date: any;
    }
```

And the HTML is:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="hireDate">Hire Date:</label>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="hireDate" id="hireDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                   [(ngModel)]="datePicker.date" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
                <img src="/assets/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
<div>{{datePicker.date}} </div>
```

But it gives me Object as a result and not the selected date.
Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Angular `DatePipe` to convert the date into the format that you wish to display.

```
<div> {{datePicker.date | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-amit?file=src/app/app.component.html)

EDIT : To convert the date object `({ "year": 2018, "month": 8, "day": 7 })` returned by ngBootstrap to `yyyy-MM-dd` format, you can do the transformation inside the `setter` method of `datePicker.date` property as follows :

module.ts

`providers : [DatePipe]`

service.ts

```
export class Datepicker {
  _date: string;
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  set date(value) {
    let date = new Date(value.year, value.month, value.year);
    this._date= this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }

  get date() { 
      return this._date
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but still it gives me that I  cannot convert Object to date. Any more solutions?

Comment: AddingEmployeeComponent.html:57 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "[object Object]" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: Please show the object data that you get by printing `{{datePicker.date | json}}`. I am not asking the error.

Comment: If I use what you are saying i am getting this: { "year": 2018, "month": 8, "day": 7 } But i want to have the date in a proper date format.

Comment: @BillUser88 check the second answer that I just posted

Comment: @BillUser88 Ok, no problem you can still do the transformation by your own within the setter method of `datePicker.date` property. Please check the updated solution.

Comment: @BillUser88 I think this line `let date = new Date(value.year, value.month, value.year);` needs to be updated to subtract 1 from `value.month` because JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11

Answer (score 1):

ng-bootstrap datepicker selection gives you an object like this

```
Model: {
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 8,
  "day": 9
}
```

You can write initialize a date object from selected model like this:

```
<div> {{ new Date(datePicker.date.year, (datePicker.date.month - 1), datePicker.date.day) | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </div>
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#popup